# pandas merge by excluding certain columns from merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes like:

`df1.columns = A, B, C, E, ..., D`

`df2.columns = A, B, C, F,  ..., D`

If I merge them, it merges on all columns. Also since the number of columns is high I don't want to specify them in `on`. I prefer to exclude the columns which I don't want to be merged. How can I do that?

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, exclude D)
```

I expect the result be like:

`mdf.columns = A, B, C, E, F ..., D_x, D_y`

Comment: just saying, why not merge then drop?

Comment: @Epsi95 I modfied my quesiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you mentioned you don't want to use `on` "since the number of columns is much".

You could still use `on` this way even if there are a lot of columns:

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[i for i in df1.columns if i != 'D'])
```

Or

By using [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns.difference(['D']).tolist())
```

Comment: Why should I drop `D`? did I say that? I want to keep `D` with different suffixes in my merged df.

Comment: I will, I should just try it.

Comment: @U11-Forward Made some changes. Please feel free to revert the changes if not ok.

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks man forgot about `difference`

Comment: shouldn't we use `list` for `on`, I have some errors running it.

Comment: I guess my question and your answer are not still general. So I did a minor midificaiton to my question which you can check, for example what if they have some uncommon columns? Can we call `on` on them as you did ?

Comment: I myself wrote an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be:

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on= df1.columns.tolist().remove('D')
```

Answer (score 1):

What about dropping the unwanted column after the merge?

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2).drop('D', axis=1)
```

or dropping before the merge:

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1.drop('D', axis=1), df2.drop('D', axis=1))
```

Comment: I said excluding from merge not droping it, I revised my question.

Comment: I see, I thought you didn't want to use `on`. Then you should go with the `on` answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using `intersection` and then `difference` on `df1` and `df2` columns:

```
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).difference(['D']).tolist())
```

The other solution could be `renaming` columns you want to exclude from merge:

```
df2.rename(columns={"D":"D_y"}, inplace=True)
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2)
```